# Spring 5 Reactive Mono - Pass Mono value to property of object and call another mono

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive, spring-mono

I'm new to the whole Spring reactive webflux.  My problem is pretty simple.  In my addActions() I am trying to get a Mono by calling getCurrentVal().  This works fine.  But I need to get the value of that and update a property (submission.stateVal).  Then pass call customService.addActions() which returns Mono.  Can this be done without using block()?

```
@Autowired
private CustomService customService;

public Mono<CustomResponse> addActions(String id, String Jwt, Submission submission) {

Mono<String> updatedStateVal = getCurrentStateVal(tpJwt, id);
// submission.setStateVal(updatedStateVal);
// return customService.addActions(id, jwt, submission);


}

private Mono<String> getCurrentVal(String tpJwt, String id) {
        return customService.findById(id, tpJwt)
                .map(r -> r.getStateVal());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return getCurrentStateVal(tpJwt, id)
    .flatMap(s -> {
        submission.setStateVal(s);
        return customService.addActions(id, tpJwt, submission);
    });
```